# HTML Beginning coding Problem with w3 validator

Tags: html

Problem: Error Stray End head Tag, Error body tag seen but an element of the same type was already open, Error stray start footer tag.

Question: Why am I getting these error? I've been looking through my book and can't figure it out.

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html lang="eng">
<head>
    <title>Josh Martin's INFO1311 Homepage</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <h1>Josh Martin's Info1311 Web Site</h1>
    <h2>Fall 2022</h2>       
</head>
<body>
            <!-- Josh Martin
             default.htm
             INFO1311
             Olberding
             09/07/22
        -->
    <div>
    <h3>Homework Assignments</h3>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="module2/assignment2.css"></a>Assignment 2</li>
        <li>Assignment 3</li>
        <li>Assignment 4</li>
        <li>Assignment 5</li>
        <li>Assignment 6</li>
        <li>Assignment 7</li>
    </ul>
    <h3>Final Project Home Page</h3>
    <h3>Important Links</h3>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="http://canvas.mccneb.edu">Canvas Course Web site</a> </li>
    <li><a href="http://www.mccneb.edu">Metro Web site</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://validator.w3.org">W3C (X)HTML Validator</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/">W3C CSS Validator</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>   
</body>
<footer>
    <p>Created by <a href=" jmmartin@mail.mccneb.edu">Josh Martin</a></p>
</footer>
</html>
```

Comment: @rayhatfield — It's HTML not XML, there's no point in adding slashes at the end of void element tags.

Comment: The `/` at the end of meta (or other single line tags) is not used in html5. Move the `<h1>Josh ....</h1>` and `<h2>Fall....</h2>` into the body section. Use 2 letter code in `lang="en"`. Move the `<footer>....</footer>` into the body section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The start and end tags for the `head`, `body`, and `html` elements are optional.

If you include an element in the `head` which isn't allowed there (such as `h1` or `h2` as you have done) then the `head` will be implicitly closed and the body implicitly started.

This has a knock of effect of making the explicit end tag for `head` and the start tag for `body` and error.

Only put elements in the `head` that are allowed there.

---

The only elements that are allowed to be children of `html` are `head` and `body`. You can't put a `footer` there, probably you meant it to be the last child of the `body` element so it needs to go before the `body` end tag.

Comment: Thank you! I fixed that issue, getting rid of the tags that were in the head only leaving the title and moving the h1, h2 into the body, but I'm still getting a footer error, i'm assuming I can't use <p> in footer, I've troubleshooted it a few times before coming bac k here

Answer (score 0):

You can't put a `footer` tag out of a `body` tag section

```
<footer>
    <p>Created by <a href=" jmmartin@mail.mccneb.edu">Josh Martin</a></p>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Instead -->

```
</body>
<footer>
    <p>Created by <a href=" jmmartin@mail.mccneb.edu">Josh Martin</a></p>
</footer>
</html>
```